# .net 4.5.1 server installation breaks Silverlight app

Tags: .net, installation, silverlight-5.0, .net-4.5

I installed the .NET 4.5.1 framework on my server and after a server restart, my ria service application starts causing issues. My RIA services calls from client Silverlîght app are getting
`Not found` error.

I tried to reinstall Silverlight 5 and ria services but after reinstalling SL5 SDK, RIA service setup ver 1.0 SP2 always showing depending error of SL4or later SDK issue.

I also copied the following ria dlls in bin as suggested in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426912(v=vs.91).aspx but still its not working.

- `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Server.dll`
- `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Hosting.dll`

Comment: I resolved the issue of RIA service dependency warning of SL4 or newer but still getting same issue from silverlight application "The remote server returned an error: Not Found at System.ServiceModel.DomainServices.Client.OperationBase.Complete(Except error)

Comment: open up the developer tools from your browser and look at network, look at the URL the Silverlight app is trying to call, copy it and try to open it in a new tab, just to check that your services are still working.